# Selection of right tool for game development

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I want to create a football (soccer) manager game as a hobby project? I want to create it for browser so in javascript

Is there some tool that will help me for that becouse I create a manager game so there is no need much interactivity and physics?

So there will be option like team tactics, stadium, PR, finance, trainings and so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing with Quintus recently - http://html5quintus.com - which gives you a nice little framework in which to build a 2D game. It seems geared toward concise code, with a prototyping/inheritance structure that makes it quite easy to start knocking together a game in HTML5/JS very quickly.

I don't know anything about the many similar engines, but there are plenty out there. Here's a good resource to help you pick one: http://html5gameengine.com

I'm guessing that you could also potentially roll your own if you had plenty of time to devote to it.